# What exactly a proper subgroup means?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

The question seems very simple, but it's confusing me as the term 'proper subgroup' has different definations in different reference books.
I read in galian(7th edition) that the subgroup of G Other than G itself are proper.
But some books, and some of my teachers believes that {e} is also an improper subgroup of G.
So I'm literally very confused whether {e} should be considered as proper subgroup or not..
Please help me.

Comment: Just like different authors use different notations, they can also use different definitions describing the same mathematical object.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the first I've heard of anyone calling the trivial subgroup improper (unless $|G|=1$), but Wikipedia confirms.

Comment: Some authors want $\{e\}$ not to be a proper subgroup, others are fine with it (possibly) being proper. There's not much you can do about your current situation other than deal with the fact that Galian's book doesn't agree with the convention that some of your teachers use: the practical way would be knowing which convention each of your teachers uses.

Comment: The word is used loosely.  Informally, I'd guess that it most frequently means "a subgroup other than $e$ or $G$ itself" but there is no universal agreement on that so anyone who uses the term should define it in context.

Comment: Please, proofread your question and correct typos.

Answer (score 4):

I think it means most of the time that the subgroup $H$ is just not equal to $G$, see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubgroup.html). In this sense, if $G$ is a non-trivial group, the subgroup $\{e\}$ is a *proper subgroup*, since it is a proper subset and satisfies the subgroup axioms.

At [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) it is written: "A proper subgroup of a group $G$ is a subgroup $H$ which is a proper subset of $G$ (that is, $H ≠ G$). This is usually represented notationally by $H < G$, read as "$H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$". *Some authors* also exclude the trivial group from being proper (that is, $H ≠ {e}$)."